# Obtener id de div, y reemplazar su contenido jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia, me pueden guiar con un detalle, tengo el siguiente codigo html:

```
<div id="div_Content"><div id="div_1390"></div><div id="div_1391"></div><div d="div_1392"></div><div id="div_1393"></div><div id="div_1394"></div><div d="div_1395"></div><div id="div_1396"></div><div id="div_1397"></div><div d="div_1398"></div><div id="div_1399"></div><div id="div_1400"></div></div>
```

Obtengo mi html de la siguiente manera:

```
 var tbl = $('#div_Content');
 var res = tbl.html();
```

Lo que requiero es reemplazar el siguiente div, en el div_Content:

```
<div id="div_1398"><span>DIV NUEVO</span></div>
```

NOTA: el div que quiero reemplazar es un codigo html que obtengo de la siguiente manera: var div = "DIV NUEVO";

he intentado obtener el id del div para reemplazarlo, pero no he logrado hacerlo, me pueden guiar?

Comment: Podrías añadir el html completo por favor.

Comment: acabo de actualizar la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo más *dinámico* a la hora de obtener los id's de cada hijo del padre `div_Content`.

Se guarda en un array donde podrás luego identificarlo y procesarlo.

He dejado un ejemplo simple donde rellenamos todos los id's.

```js
var ids;

var arrId = [];

$('#div_Content').children().each(function(){
     
     var ids = $(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/g, '');     
     arrId.push(ids);
});

// Para reemplazar el contenido de cada div con el id especifico:

var contenido_ejemplo = 0;

arrId.forEach(function(el) {

  console.log('Id obtenido: '+ el); // Todos los id's obtenidos
  
  // Ejemplo de reemplazar/rellenar el contenido:  
  $('#div_' + el).html( contenido_ejemplo++);
});
```

```html
<div id="div_Content">
  <div id="div_1390"></div>
  <div id="div_1391"></div>
  <div id="div_1392"></div>
  <div id="div_1393"></div>
  <div id="div_1394"></div>
  <div id="div_1395"></div>
  <div id="div_1396"></div>
  <div id="div_1397"></div>
  <div id="div_1398"></div>
  <div id="div_1399"></div>
  <div id="div_1400"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Saludos podrias hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<h3>DIV CONTENT</h3>
<div id="div_Content" style="border-style: solid; border-color:red">
</div>
<h3>DIV 1398</h3>
<div id="div_1398"  style="border-style: solid; border-color:green">
<span>contenido div 1398</span>
</div>


<script>
var div_1 = document.getElementById('div_1398');
var div_2 = document.getElementById('div_Content');
//agregando el contenido del div 1 en div 2
div_2.innerHTML = div_1.innerHTML;
//eliminar contenido div_1398
//div_1.innerHTML = '';
</script>
```

Como veras tengo dos div agregue estilo css para diferenciarlos, en este caso solo uso Javascript puro, lo que hace basicamente es tomar el id de los div deseados, agregamos el contenido mediante innerHTML, si deseas eliminar el contenido del div_1398, lo haces como lo ves en el comentado.

**Resultado:**

[image: result_divs]

**JQUERY**

```
<h3>DIV CONTENT</h3>
<div id="div_Content" style=" border-style: solid; border-color:red"></div>
<h3>DIV 1398</h3>
<div id="div_1398" style=" border-style: solid; border-color:green">
  <span>CONTENIDO DIV 1398</span>
</div>
<script>
//contenido div_1398
div_1398 = $('#div_1398').html();
//agregar contenido div_1398  a div_content
 $('#div_Content').html(div_1398);
</script>
```

Espero te pueda guiar y sirva ..!!